# _CastError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, dart

Пытаюсь обработать JSON ответ, необходимо выделить "data" (Использую CoinMarketCap)

```
{
    "status": {
        "timestamp": "2019-03-04T11:51:50.249Z",
        "error_code": 0,
        "error_message": null,
        "elapsed": 5,
        "credit_count": 1
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "slug": "bitcoin",
            "circulating_supply": 17570250,
            "total_supply": 17570250,
            "max_supply": 21000000,
            "date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
            "num_market_pairs": 6722,
            "tags": [
                "mineable"
            ],
            "platform": null,
            "cmc_rank": 1,
            "last_updated": "2019-03-04T11:51:23.000Z",
            "quote": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 3761.08116396,
                    "volume_24h": 8472364962.15305,
                    "percent_change_1h": 0.463327,
                    "percent_change_24h": -2.66362,
                    "percent_change_7d": -2.18666,
                    "market_cap": 66083136321.06819,
                    "last_updated": "2019-03-04T11:51:23.000Z"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1027,
            "name": "Ethereum",
            "symbol": "ETH",
            "slug": "ethereum",
            "circulating_supply": 105119454.4991,
            "total_supply": 105119454.4991,
            "max_supply": null,
            "date_added": "2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z",
            "num_market_pairs": 4766,
            "tags": [
                "mineable"
            ],
            "platform": null,
            "cmc_rank": 2,
            "last_updated": "2019-03-04T11:51:19.000Z",
            "quote": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 127.789942421,
                    "volume_24h": 3989111074.78033,
                    "percent_change_1h": 1.32918,
                    "percent_change_24h": -5.41225,
                    "percent_change_7d": -8.35691,
                    "market_cap": 13433209037.766918,
                    "last_updated": "2019-03-04T11:51:19.000Z"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 52,
            "name": "XRP",
            "symbol": "XRP",
            "slug": "ripple",
            "circulating_supply": 41432141931,
            "total_supply": 99991683860,
            "max_supply": 100000000000,
            "date_added": "2013-08-04T00:00:00.000Z",
            "num_market_pairs": 332,
            "tags": [],
            "platform": null,
            "cmc_rank": 3,
            "last_updated": "2019-03-04T11:51:04.000Z",
            "quote": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 0.305550941952,
                    "volume_24h": 663669735.085875,
                    "percent_change_1h": 0.650488,
                    "percent_change_24h": -2.7938,
                    "percent_change_7d": -0.18049,
                    "market_cap": 12659629994.106007,
                    "last_updated": "2019-03-04T11:51:04.000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Но получаю ошибку _CastError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map' in type cast)

```
_loadCC() async {
    const headers = '2a675b19-8c02-43bd-901a-6dfa0f0cd376';
    final response = await http.get(
        "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=${headers}&limit=50");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // print(response.body);
      // var allData =
      //     (json.decode(response.body) as Map)['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
      // var allData = (jsonDecode(response.body).map((e) => e.toList()));
      var allData =
          (json.decode(response.body) as Map)["data"] as Map<String, dynamic>;
      var ccdataList = List<CCData>();
      allData.forEach((String key, dynamic value) {
        var record = CCData(
            name: value['name'],
            symbol: value['symbol'],
            rank: value['cmc_rank']);
        ccdataList.add(record);
      });
      setState(() {
        data = ccdataList;
      });
    }
  }

  List<Widget> _buildList() {
    return data
        .map((CCData f) => ListTile(
              title: Text(f.name),
              subtitle: Text(f.symbol),
              leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text(f.rank.toString())),
              trailing: Text('\$${f.price.toString()}'),
            ))
        .toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Предложу все-таки по-другому парсить json. [Вот](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing) статья на офсайте Flutter, а вот [еще](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json). Все стандартными средствами языка.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше используйте [json_serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable), с ним будет легче и быстрее.
Примеры использования: [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json), [Medium 1](https://medium.com/flutter-io/some-options-for-deserializing-json-with-flutter-7481325a4450), [Medium 2](https://medium.com/flutterpub/validating-json-in-flutter-6f07ec9344f8)

---

```
import 'dart:convert';

CoinMarketCap coinMarketCapFromJson(String str) => CoinMarketCap.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String coinMarketCapToJson(CoinMarketCap data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class CoinMarketCap {
    List<Data> data;

    CoinMarketCap({
        this.data,
    });

    factory CoinMarketCap.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CoinMarketCap(
        data: List<Data>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Data.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Data {
    int id;
    String name;
    String symbol;
    String slug;
    double circulatingSupply;
    double totalSupply;
    int maxSupply;
    DateTime dateAdded;
    int numMarketPairs;
    List<String> tags;
    dynamic platform;
    int cmcRank;
    DateTime lastUpdated;
    Quote quote;

    Data({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.symbol,
        this.slug,
        this.circulatingSupply,
        this.totalSupply,
        this.maxSupply,
        this.dateAdded,
        this.numMarketPairs,
        this.tags,
        this.platform,
        this.cmcRank,
        this.lastUpdated,
        this.quote,
    });

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        symbol: json["symbol"],
        slug: json["slug"],
        circulatingSupply: json["circulating_supply"].toDouble(),
        totalSupply: json["total_supply"].toDouble(),
        maxSupply: json["max_supply"] == null ? null : json["max_supply"],
        dateAdded: DateTime.parse(json["date_added"]),
        numMarketPairs: json["num_market_pairs"],
        tags: List<String>.from(json["tags"].map((x) => x)),
        platform: json["platform"],
        cmcRank: json["cmc_rank"],
        lastUpdated: DateTime.parse(json["last_updated"]),
        quote: Quote.fromJson(json["quote"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "symbol": symbol,
        "slug": slug,
        "circulating_supply": circulatingSupply,
        "total_supply": totalSupply,
        "max_supply": maxSupply == null ? null : maxSupply,
        "date_added": dateAdded.toIso8601String(),
        "num_market_pairs": numMarketPairs,
        "tags": List<dynamic>.from(tags.map((x) => x)),
        "platform": platform,
        "cmc_rank": cmcRank,
        "last_updated": lastUpdated.toIso8601String(),
        "quote": quote.toJson(),
    };
}

class Quote {
    Usd usd;

    Quote({
        this.usd,
    });

    factory Quote.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Quote(
        usd: Usd.fromJson(json["USD"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "USD": usd.toJson(),
    };
}

class Usd {
    double price;
    double volume24H;
    double percentChange1H;
    double percentChange24H;
    double percentChange7D;
    double marketCap;
    DateTime lastUpdated;

    Usd({
        this.price,
        this.volume24H,
        this.percentChange1H,
        this.percentChange24H,
        this.percentChange7D,
        this.marketCap,
        this.lastUpdated,
    });

    factory Usd.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Usd(
        price: json["price"].toDouble(),
        volume24H: json["volume_24h"].toDouble(),
        percentChange1H: json["percent_change_1h"].toDouble(),
        percentChange24H: json["percent_change_24h"].toDouble(),
        percentChange7D: json["percent_change_7d"].toDouble(),
        marketCap: json["market_cap"].toDouble(),
        lastUpdated: DateTime.parse(json["last_updated"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "price": price,
        "volume_24h": volume24H,
        "percent_change_1h": percentChange1H,
        "percent_change_24h": percentChange24H,
        "percent_change_7d": percentChange7D,
        "market_cap": marketCap,
        "last_updated": lastUpdated.toIso8601String(),
    };
}
```